# Empty database table at certain times

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that I need to empty every 24 hours, or whatever time that I set it to. I don't want the table deleted, just emptied. I'm wondering what the best method would be to do this using PHP? Really appreciate any direction you can provide for me.

Comment: use cron job to run the script to empty the table

Comment: Does your host allow cron jobs or scheduled tasks?

Comment: Use a cron job for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html).

Query can be something like this:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE time < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

Comment: I think he doesn’t want to delete _records_ based on timestamp, but to empty the whole table instead – so that would be a simple `TRUNCATE your_table` query instead.